# using curly braces in v-text field vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

here's my code:

```
v-text="${item.name} ${item.surname} ${(item.place_name ? ' (' + item.place_name + ')' : '')}"
```

but I got the erro saying that "{" is unexpected. Can I use it in vuetify?

Comment: I am not able to get the issue here. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: You're using template strings in the `v-text` binding so you probably need to wrap all of it in backticks so that it will be evaluated as such. A better way is to actually offload this to a method, so that you abstract the logic away from your template entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the backticks

```
v-text="`${item.name} ${item.surname} ${(item.place_name ? ' (' + item.place_name + ')' : '')`}"
```

That above should work just fine, remember you can also use interpolation with double curly braces like:

```
{{ `${item.name} ${item.surname} ${(item.place_name ? ' (' + item.place_name + ')' : '')` }}
```

within the tags you created instead of the v-text directive

and you could also save that value in a properly named computed property and reference it like

```
v-text="myComputedProperty"
```

so you remove that logic from your template

Comment: you can't use double curly for attributes

Comment: I meant within the tags like <span> {{ attrib }} </span>

Comment: `v-text` will escape HTML, but printing it directly in the DOM using curly brackets will not.